# How do I deal with references in Firestore DataConverter?

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Ok, so I'm working on a project (written in TypeScript using Vue) using Firestore and I prefer a model driven approach to data, so I have created classes to represent all of my models. I link some of those models together using references, so I don't have to store 300 documents with the same data. Since I'm using a model driven approach, I decided to use [Firestore's `FirestoreDataConverter`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FirestoreDataConverter) to help me with getting my data into and out of the database.

The problem I am now running into is that I cannot write an asynchronous `fromFirestore` function and return a `Promise` because Typescript keeps complaining that the return types on `fromFirestore` don't match because I'm returning a Promise. Code for one full class (with some minor redactions) listed below.

```
import { firestore } from 'firebase/app';

import { 
  AdministrativeArea,
  AdministrativeAreaSchema,
  AdministrativeAreaConverter
} from './administrative-area';
import {
  Country,
  CountryCollection,
  CountrySchema,
  CountryConverter,
} from './country';
import { Model } from './model';

export interface AddressSchema {
  administrativeArea: firestore.DocumentReference<AdministrativeAreaSchema>;
  country: firestore.DocumentReference<CountrySchema>;
  locality: string;
  postalCode: string;
  premise?: string;
  subAdministrativeArea?: string;
  subPremise?: string;
  thoroughfare: string;
}

export interface AddressViewModel {
  administrativeArea: AdministrativeArea;
  country: Country;
  id?: string;
  locality: string;
  postalCode: string;
  premise?: string;
  subAdministrativeArea?: string;
  subPremise?: string;
  thoroughfare: string;
}

export class Address extends Model {
  private _administrativeArea: AdministrativeArea;
  private _country: Country;
  private _locality: string;
  private _postalCode: string;
  private _premise?: string;
  private _subAdministrativeArea?: string;
  private _subPremise?: string;
  private _thoroughfare: string;

  constructor(opts: AddressViewModel) {
    super(opts.id);

    this._administrativeArea = opts.administrativeArea;
    this._country = opts.country;
    this._locality = opts.locality;
    this._postalCode = opts.postalCode;
    this._premise = opts.premise;
    this._subAdministrativeArea = opts.subAdministrativeArea;
    this._subPremise = opts.subPremise;
    this._thoroughfare = opts.thoroughfare;
  }

  public get administrativeArea(): AdministrativeArea {
    return this._administrativeArea;
  }

  public get country(): Country {
    return this._country;
  }

  public get locality(): string {
    return this._locality;
  }

  public get postalCode(): string {
    return this._postalCode;
  }

  public get premise(): string {
    return this._premise ? this._premise : '';
  }

  public get subAdministrativeArea(): string {
    return this._subAdministrativeArea ? this._subAdministrativeArea : '';
  }

  public get subPremise(): string {
    return this._subPremise ? this._subPremise : '';
  }

  public get thoroughfare(): string {
    return this._thoroughfare;
  }
}

export const AddressConverter = {
  toFirestore(address: Address): firestore.DocumentData {
    return {
      administrativeArea: CountryCollection
        .doc(address.country.id)
        .collection('administrativeAreas')
        .doc(address.administrativeArea.id),
      country: CountryCollection.doc(address.country.id),
      locality: address.locality,
      postalCode: address.postalCode,
      premise: address.premise,
      subAdministrativeArea: address.subAdministrativeArea,
      subPremise: address.subPremise,
      thoroughfare: address.thoroughfare,
    };
  },

  async fromFirestore(snapshot: firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot<AddressSchema>,
    options?: firestore.SnapshotOptions): Promise<Address> {
    const data = snapshot.data(options);

    const countrySnap = await data.country
      .withConverter(CountryConverter)
      .get();
    const country = countrySnap.data() as Country;

    const adminAreaSnap = await data.administrativeArea
      .withConverter(AdministrativeAreaConverter)
      .get();
    const administrativeArea = adminAreaSnap.data() as AdministrativeArea;

    return Promise.resolve(
      new Address({
        administrativeArea,
        country,
        id: snapshot.id,
        locality: data.locality,
        postalCode: data.postalCode,
        premise: data.premise,
        subAdministrativeArea: data.subAdministrativeArea,
        subPremise: data.subPremise,
        thoroughfare: data.thoroughfare,
      })
    );
  },
};
```

EDIT: I forgot to mention that as a stop gap, until I can find a solution, I'm just doing empty do/while loops. For example:

```
let country: Country | null = null;

data.country
  .withConverter(CountryConverter)
  .get()
  .then((res) => {
    country = country.data() as Country;
  });

do ; while (country === null)
```

Comment: Can you share the error message?

Comment: The API is not equipped to deal with asynchronous conversions.  You will have to manually write code to wait on each promise, and continue only after they are all resolved (e.g. Promise.all).

Comment: @Max The error message is basically a Typescript error that tells me the return type of `Promise<Address>` is incompatible with return type of `Address` because it lacks properties, blah, blah, blah

Comment: @DougStevenson Yeah, that was kind of my thought process with the empty do/while loop.